# Is there a batch processing framework that could be used for C++ applications?

Tags: c++, frameworks

In my team we develop several command-line C++ applications that work together; they're currently run by hand in separate windows, and after a while managing windows gets really confusing.

I'm looking for a better way to manage the processing of these applications; ideally it would have a GUI with the ability to do the following:

- start applications in a specified order
- display application status
- close particular applications

Is there anything available that does this type of thing or would we need to develop our own? Is there a better way than this?

Answer (score 2):

I run a basic batch scheduler on Windows XP by scheduling a Windows command file to execute at a certain time, and putting the various batch processes in the Windows command file.

I did a Google search on "c++ batch scheduling" (without the quotes) and came up with a few candidates.

- [Enterprise Batch Scheduling](http://www.advsyscon.com/products/activebatch/batch_scheduling.asp?gclid=CO2ukdHgyqwCFcZM4AodkVbtqg#.TsqyUWP0veg?utm_campaign=AdWords&utm_source=PPC&_kk=batch%20process%20scheduling&_kt=5fa1c321-0030-4fdc-8d4f-6362f5633132)
- [Vizant Software](http://www.vinzantsoftware.com/?gclid=CPzX8uDgyqwCFYTe4Aodbzqspw)
- [Skybot Software](http://www.skybotsoftware.com/landingpage/adwords/modern-affordable-enterprise-scheduling?gclid=CMWf3a7hyqwCFcFw4AoddhQXrA)

Answer (score 0):

Batch processing, there's either bash if you're on Linux, or Windows Scripting Host (or Powershell) if you're on Windows.

Neither has a GUI, but they can both be scripted to call your apps as you like.